# Can I use c# methods when serializing to JSON

Tags: c#, json

I am using JSON.Net to convert the data from my c# program to JSON format using JSON.NET. I was wondering if there was any way in which I could use methods that I use in my c# program when serialising to json?

Bit of background context:

There exists a class `Students` which has attributes`String StudentName`, `Guid StudentId` and `Dictionary<String, Int> Grades Record` where subject names are the keys and grades are the values.

There exists another class `ClassOfStudents` which has an attribute `List<Student> Students`.

I am trying to print out the list of all the students names. I have managed to do this on c# with the method below:

```
public static void ViewStudentsPool()
{
Console.Write(Line);
Console.WriteLine("\nPlease find updated students pool below");
Console.Write(Line + "\n");
foreach (var studentname in ClassOfStudents.Students)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("Student Id: " + studentname.StudentId + "| Student Name: " + studentname.StudentName);
  }
Console.Write(Line + "\n\n");
}
```

I was wondering if I could then use this method when serialising to JSON.

I currently have the below, which prints out all attributes of the students which I do not want, I only want to print their names out.

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\Students.txt"))
using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
   writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
   serializer.Serialize(writer, ClassOfStudents.Students );
}
```

I have tried replacing  `ClassOfStudents.Students`on the last line with `ViewStudentsPool()` but it shows an error.

Any help  on how I can print out only the student names?

Thanks

Comment: KISS: make classes that represent exactly what you want in JSON and convert to that structure?

Comment: Would you show us how the JSON looks like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple approach would be to just map your `ClassOfStudents.Students` list to the structure that you're looking for, using LINQ, for example:

```
var studentsWithNamesOnly = ClassOfStudents.Students
    .Select(x => new { x.StudentName });
```

You can take this output and serialise *that* instead of your original `ClassOfStudents.Students` variable, like this:

```
serializer.Serialize(writer, studentsWithNamesOnly);
```

This would produce something like this:

```
[
    { "StudentName": "Name1" },
    { "StudentName": "Name2" },
    ...
]
```

You don't have to create a new anonymous object in the `Select` like I've done here: You could format a string like your original example, if that's what's needed.